# Upgrading python 3.1 to 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I'm upgrading from 3.1 to 3.2.  Other than looking at 3.1's site-packages directory to see what packages I've been using so that I can install them for 3.2, are there other places I should check for things to install or other issues to look at?

I'm not asking about changes to the language between 3.1 and 3.2. I just want to make sure I've installed and configured everything I had in 3.1.  I realize argparse is built into 3.2, so I don't have to install that.

I'm running Windows, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, installing the modules you have installed in 3.1 should be all you need to do. Also of course, if you are compiling from scratch, make sure you have all the libraries installed you have when you compiled 3.1, as some of the standard lib otherwise may be unavailable.

Comment: Do modules get installed with a mention in site-packages?  I'm just using the windows installer, rather than compiling from scratch.

Comment: With a "mention" no. They get installed into site-packages, yes. Unless your python setup is non-standard, but since you use the Windows installer that's unlikely.

Comment: Sounds as if an examination of site-packages is all I need. By "mention" I meant appearing in.

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. The `pip freeze` was cool it shows versions too, but pip doesn't support Python 3 yet, I think.

Comment: personally, i would also have a look along the PYTHONPATH. also, there are a set of settings stored in the registry, which describe each python installation, which may tell you more about what is installed and where it is installed.

Comment: note that, when using the standard installer on windows, you can have multiple versions of python installed, without any problem (especially since [PEP 3147](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/)). the only drawback is that only the last version of the interpreter is registered system-wide for automatic execution of python scripts: in order to use a previously installed version, you have to specify the full path to the python executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install 3.2 in parallel with 3.1, simply by putting it in a different directory. Then if at some point you find you are missing something from your environment you can always figure out what you had before.

Nearly everything you installed that's Python-related should be in site-packages, so it should be mostly a matter of keeping track of those packages and installing them again in 3.2

If you have `pip` you can use `pip freeze` to generate a list of what's installed in your environment.

Comment: I have installed 3.2 in parallel, in case there's a problem with 3.2.  I'll look into pip, but meanwhile, where else might something be if it's not in site-packages?

Comment: Does pip support 3.1?  pip's page only lists 2.4 - 2.7 and a post on SO from a few months ago says pip does not support 3

Comment: @foosion: No, pip doesn't support Python 3 yet.